# Replace with re.sub AFTER matching pattern

Tags: python, regex

i have a regex substitution that i cannot figure out.

```
s2 = re.compile("^DATA_ARRAY (.*?};)", re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)    
result = re.sub(s2, "newData", inputData)
```

The problem is that it replaces the "DATA_ARRAY" part as well. I need to replace only the text that comes AFTER the "DATA_ARRAY" part. I have placed the data in a group in the s2 `(.*?};)`but cannot figure out how to use the re.sub function to replace only the required part.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s2 = re.compile("^(DATA_ARRAY )(.*?};)", re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)    
result = re.sub(s2, r"\1newData", inputData)
```

You can capture the `first group` and replace via `backreferencing`

or simply

```
s2 = re.compile("^DATA_ARRAY (.*?};)", re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)    
result = re.sub(s2, "DATA_ARRAY newData", inputData)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me on the right track! I actually had to use a named backreference since the "newData" was in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
s2 = re.compile("(?<=^DATA_ARRAY )(.*?};)", re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)    
result = re.sub(s2, "newData", inputData)
```

You can just have a lookbehind assertion `(?<=___)`.

Comment: really?? lookbehinds wont match the patterns..?

Comment: I tried and did not get any matches with this regex.